# Adding tapgesture to UIImageview

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Im trying to add a tapgesture to UIImageview. but the code bellow which im using right now is not working.

I have added this to my viewdidload (notice that LabelNewsImage is my UIImageview):

```
LabelNewsImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureEnlarge = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
tapGestureEnlarge.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.LabelNewsImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureEnlarge];
```

Comment: You enabled user interaction on a different view to the one the gesture is added to. Is that one enabled too?

Comment: There is no need to use the `inputView` property. Remove it and add it to `self.LabelNewsImage` only.

Comment: @NikolaKirev Oh im sorry it is supposed to be self.LabelNewsImage. It doesnt work on that either. I also corrected my question.

Comment: @Wain I have enabled user interaction on LabelNewsImage which the tapgesture is added to.

Comment: When is this code? Is `LabelNewsImage` a valid reference at that time?

Comment: What do you men by "Valid Reference"? LabelNewsImage is a UIImageview. Its the view that i wanna add the tabgesture to.

Comment: wain wants to know when the code executes if the imageview is nil or not.. add a log to check or use breakpoint and print in console

Comment: @Dante: Ok i NSLoged it and yes it was null. but it displays the image assigned to it. Ok so what now?

Comment: @Wain I Nsloged it and it was empty! It displays the image tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly connect `LabelNewsImage` to the image view instance. Presumably `LabelNewsImage` is an `IBOutlet` and your image view is created in an XIB or Storyboard. You need to drag a connection from the `LabelNewsImage` property to the image view to connect them.

See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html) (including [the video](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/CreatingOutlet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH15)).

Comment: I have created everything programmatically. LabelNewsImage is just a UIImageview. I just subview it to the main view and it works. I mean the photo and everything works fine but it doesnt recognize the tap event.

Comment: Show more code then. How you create it and how that code relates to the code you have shown so far.

Comment: this is how i create LabelNewsImage: 
LabelNewsImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13,10,100,85)];
[scrollView addSubview:LabelNewsImage];

Answer (score 0):

The response selector tapGesture:
Is it probable that you write the method like

```
- (void)tapGesture
{
    // TODO:
}
```

But it should like this

```
- (void)tapGesture:(NSDictonary *)dic
{
    // TODO:
}
```

Comment: TapGesture method doesnt need any input object.

Comment: @user3687 But the tapGesture method is called as tapGesture: not tapGesture in your code. On another hand, `LabelNewsImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and `[self.LabelNewsImage addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureEnlarge];`, I think you should only use `self.LabelNewsImage` or `LabelNewsImage`, not both together